# Can a queue be implemented using only a hash-table?

Tags: data-structures, queue, hashtable

what i mean is that the implementation can only allocate a small (O(1)/O(log n)) amount of memory independently - most of the queue's data must be inside the hash table.

EDIT: this data structure should support (Push,Pop,Top,Len) operations, but under the hood, instead of being a linked-list/array, it will use a hash-table. The majority O(n) memory needed will be contained in a hash-table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any list-like data structure can be represented by a hash table, where every element in the list is mapped to its position. So this list: `[a, b, c, d]` can be represented by a hash table like this:

```
0: a
1: b
2: c
3: d
```

A queue is a FIFO data structure: first in, first out. So elements are popped in the same order they were pushed. It can be modeled with an list-like data structure where we push new elements to the list by adding them to the tail and we pop elements by taking them from the head.

> the implementation can only allocate a small (O(1)/O(log n)) amount of memory independently

The only necessary data to handle independently from the hash table itself are the `head` and `tail` indexes.

So, using the `[a, b, c, d]` example, our head points to index `0` (which corresponds to `a`) and our tail to index `3` (which corresponds to `d`).

To push a new element to the queue (e.g. `e`), we insert it into our hash table with key `tail + 1`, that is `4`, and we increment our `tail` by 1.

To pop an element, we get the element at the `head` position, remove it from the hash table and increment `head` by 1.

After this, our hash table ends up like this:

```
1: b
2: c
3: d
4: e
```

With this implementation, `top` and `len` are trivial to implement.

This basic idea can be extended to handle more complex hash tables.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question. after googling if it's advisable to do that. From what I know, the goal of a queue is to have constant retrieval time and constant removal time. 0(1). the best implementation would be a linked list approach or an array using the 'Unshift' and 'pop' method